# Rolling Filter in For Loop Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to run a rolling filter on a dataframe (500 rows and 10 columns) using following code but it gives me an error. Could someone please advise what is the issue here?

`df[(df['Y'] > 0.0) & (df['X'] < 0.0)]['X']` ----> this works fine. When I use it in for loop with respect to columns like this

```
for col in df.columns:
     df[(df['Y'] > 0.0) & (df[col] < 0.0)][col]
```

also works fine.

but when I am inserting location for rows like this
`df[(df[0:10]['Y'] > 0.0) & (df[0:10]['X'] < 0.0)]['X']` ----> gives this error "IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match)."

**the reason for selecting [0:10] rows is that because I want to use it in For Loop so that at any day, I only have filtered result for last 10 days.**

Is there a better way to do it? Appreciate your help. Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(df[0:10]['Y'] > 0.0) & (df[0:10]['X'] == 0.0) is pandas.core.series.Series

And this Series`s size is 10

But df`s size is not 10

So you change the df`s size like this

df[0:10][(df[0:10]['Y'] > 0.0) & (df[0:10]['X'] == 0.0)]['X']